# Dynamically parsing XML into non-NSString variables

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse through an XML I'm getting from a webservice with an `NSXMLParserDelegate`.  The `NSObject` I want to put the data into (I'll just call it `MyObject`) has `@property`s that are not `NSString`s (there are some `NSDate`s, some `NSNumber`s, and maybe at some point in the future some primitives).

Since the XML is all a big string, I'm getting errors and crashes when I try to just directly put the values from the XML into my properties (I'm using `[myObject setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];` in my `parser:didEndElement:...`, which normally works fine - when `key` is a `NSString`).  I didn't really expect this to work, but I figured it was worth a shot.

The easiest thing to do is just hardcode all of it, so if I have an '@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *age;' on my object, when I find the `<age>25</age>` part of my XML, I do `MyObject.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[currentElementValue intValue]];`.  The problem with this is it is very rigid - I'd like this code to be more dynamic than that.  I don't want to have to know what all the properties of my object are ahead of time.

I've also tried checking what the `class` of the property is, then doing some conversion before entering a value (so something like `[myObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[currentElementValue intValue] forKey:elementName];` if the property `isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]`.  The problem with this is that this is the first time that property is used, so it is `nil`, and therefore doesn't have a class.  So this approach doesn't really work either.

Am I doing this completely wrong?  It seems like it should be fairly typical to get data from an XML and put it into non-`NSString` variables, but I can't seem to get it to work.

If anyone needs to see more code to get a better understanding of how I've this is set up or what I've already tried, let me know.

---

EDIT:
I've come up with a quick example of what I'm trying to do.  Suppose I have the following XML:

```
<Object>
    <ITEM_NUMBER>4</ITEM_NUMBER>
    <IS_AWESOME>YES</IS_AWESOME>
    <AWESOMENESS>9000.1</AWESOMENESS>
</Object>
```

that I want to parse into an instance of `MyObject` (an `NSObject` subclass)

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int ITEM_NUMBER;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL IS_AWESOME;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float AWESOMENESS;

@end
```

And a second XML

```
<OtherObject>
    <PRICE>4.99</PRICE>
    <QUANTITY>5</QUANTITY>
    <FOR_RESALE>NO</FOR_RESALE>
</OtherObject>
```

that will go into an instance of `OtherObject` (also `NSObject` subclass)

```
@interface OtherObject: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) int QUANTITY;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL FOR_RESALE;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float PRICE;

@end
```

I want to create a "template" parser (which has `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *instance;` and then `NSMutableString *currentElementValue` as an ivar)

```
...
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentElementValue setString:string];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([[self.instance valueForKey:elementName] isKindOfClass:int])
    {
        [self.instance setValue:[currentElementValue intValue] forKey:elementName];
    }
    else if ([[self.instance valueForKey:elementName] isKindOfClass:float])
    {
        [self.instance setValue:[currentElementValue floatValue] forKey:elementName];
    }
    else if ([[self.instance valueForKey:elementName] isKindOfClass:BOOL])
    {
        [self.instance setValue:[currentElementValue boolValue] forKey:elementName];
    }
    else if ...
}
...
```

Then, I just subclass that "template" parser for each of my different XMLs and overwrite the `init` method so that

```
self.instance = [[MyObject alloc] init];
```

or

```
self.instance = [[OtherObject alloc] init];
```

as appropriate.  I have a lot of webservices I'm calling that I will be getting similarly structured XML from, so only having to change 1 line in the parsers for each is something that is very desirable.  Having all the rest of the parser code in a single "template" class will make maintaining, reading, and debugging the code so much easier.

Obviously, the problem I'm having is `isKindOfClass` doesn't accept `int`, `float`, or `BOOL` as inputs.  Is there anything similar that I can use instead?

Comment: It's common for the parser delegate to know about the properties of your objects. There's nothing wrong with creating the `NSNumber` object from the XML value and assigning it to your object. However, if you wanted to make your code a little more reusable, you could create a loader for each of your model classes, to avoid having all your code in the `parser:didEndElement:` method. Then just pass your attributes to each loader.

Comment: @CraigOtis: If I do the "loader" idea you suggested, I'm going to need to essentially write a custom setter for every property in my objects right?  So really I still have to do the same amount of work as hardcoding it in the `didEndElement:` method, it just moves where that work is done, correct?

Comment: Your properties should all have setters anyway. You should *not* rely on the `setValue:forKey:` methods to create and customize your objects.

Comment: @CraigOtis: Well the way I understand it, the setters are automatically created for all `@property`s.  I've never had to create/overwrite one myself.  When I create the object that hold the data I read from the XML, I make sure I have a property that matches each element in the XML.  That's what makes `setValue:forKey:` work, and it was my impression that was the best-practice way of setting it up.  I'm also creating the XML that is sent by the webservice, so will will always know what to expect ahead of time - but I suppose if that wasn't the case it could cause some trouble.

Comment: I would avoid `setValue:forKey:` unless you have a very specific reason to use it. The setters *are* automatically created for you if you're using properties, and you should be using those to customize your objects. Just use `myObject.age = ...` in your loader class for whatever type `myObject` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem with this is that this is the first time that property is used, so it is nil, and therefore doesn't have a class.

Objective-C allows to **query class properties at runtime**, so introspecting the property type and using an appropriate trnsformation is one way to go.

You can read more about runtime [at Mike Ash's blog](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-13-intro-to-the-objective-c-runtime.html) or see *[Objective C Introspection/Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection)*.

However, **this specific problem has been encountered by many other people**, so there are quite a few solutions: as said in *[iOS Most mature REST service library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993272/ios-most-mature-rest-service-library)* RESTKit is one good example of such a library; MagicRecord is another.

You can easily find a couple more libraries to check out before you decide to implement your own solution.

Comment: I've already got most of the parsing and supporting stuff figured out, so I think the introspection thing sounds like what will be easiest for me at this point.  I read over the links you provided, but I didn't see anything that actually described how to tell the variable type for a given `property`, which is where I'm stuck right now.  Do you know the syntax for doing that?

Comment: Ah, that does require some clicking through. It's `property_getAttributes(property)`.Look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html or play with https://github.com/mikeash/MAObjCRuntime/blob/master/RTProperty.m

Comment: Just a note: you need to `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Of course I could just override the `init` method of `MyObject` to alloc-init all my properties to empty values, which should solve the `nil` problem I referenced in my OP, but that just feels really hacky.  It may be the only option though.

---

EDIT: this approach totally falls apart with the example in the EDIT in the OP.  KVC will turn `int`s, `float`s, and `BOOL`s all to `NSNumber`s, without any way of knowing what they originally where.  Which means I won't be able to call `[currentElementValue intValue]`, `[currentElementValue floatValue]`, or `[currentElementValue boolValue]` as appropriate.